# device lookup by user agent using WURFL

Tags: wurfl

I've received a request from an internal user that I'm not sure how to respond. I was asked to create a list of all possible user agent strings that might be used by WURFL and the device response generated by WURFL. Basically, a lookup list for user agent string and corresponding device.
Is that possible? If so, how should I approach this?

Comment: You could use another device detection repository such as Device Atlas or 51degrees.mobi (my company) and compare the responses. 51Degrees.mobi is over 99.9% accurate. You can contact 51Degrees.mobi via the web site if you'd like an evaluation.

Comment: Thank you, James! I do not need any evaluation, just need to get the lookup list, if it's possible at all.

Comment: It's not practical to use a look up list as the number of useragent strings are vast. Over 130 million and growing each day. There is a Trie based routine on our site which works very well.